# How would you create a list of Objects with randomly generated elements in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, object, random

**Making objects with random values and storing them in an array**

I am working on a program for marine vessel operations. To test out some programs I have been trying to generate a list of random ships with different elements like names, serial numbers, a few Booleans and other integers.
Here is an example:

```
tfu
Serial Number: 8011148632
Maximum Cargo Size: 14
Maximum Ship Speed: 23
Vessel is on export lane
Ship Class 3
```

I have developed a system to randomly generate the data but have only figured out how to store it in a String variable and then as a list.
List Storage:

```
      String shipDe = randomName + "\n"
             + "Serial Number: " + serial + "\n"
             + "Maximum Cargo Size: " + cargoSize + "\n"
             + "Maximum Ship Speed: "+ shipSpeed + "\n"
             + located + "\n"
             + classeses + "\n";

      return shipDe;
```

Here I make a list of Strings

```
public String[] liste(int shipN) {
        int okay = shipN;
        String[] lister= new String[okay];

        for (int i = 0; i < okay; i++){
            randomShip shippi = new randomShip();

         String hello = shippi.shipDetails();
         lister[i] = hello;

        }

        return lister;
```

For my project, I need all the data to be separate, so that I can search the list for ships with a certain cargo size, class or speed, and then check where the ship is. I don't want the data to be stored as a string, but as a single object which I can store is a list.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, never add solutions directly inside the question. If your question will be reopened you'll could add your solution in the answer section. In the meantime you should read carefully the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) before to formulate other questions.

Answer (score 0):

(Solved)

To solve this problem I first added a setter to the shipDetails (object) class. This helps in the future for adding your own ships

```
 public shipDetails bigSetter(String n, int s, int cS, int sS, int l, String cL){
        shipDetails aShip = new shipDetails();
        aShip.randomName = n;
        aShip.serial = s;
        aShip.cargoSize = cS;
        aShip.shipSpeed = sS;
        aShip.located = l;
        aShip.classLevel = cL;
        String locateds = "";

        if(l == 1){
            locateds = "Docked Vessel";
        } else if (l == 2){
            locateds = "On Import Lane";
        } else if (l == 3){
            locateds = "On Export Lane";
        }
        aShip.shipSummary = n + "\n"
                + "Serial Number: " + s + "\n"
                + "Maximum Cargo Size: " + cS + "\n"
                + "Maximum Ship Speed: "+ sS + "\n"
                + locateds + "\n"
                + cL + "\n";

        return aShip;

    }
```

If I just wanted the random answers I could have set everything equal to an output from a randomGenerator class. I kept the classes separate of course but the randomGenerator class made a random name, serial and other characteristics and returned a shipDetails object made via the bigSetter, however this is not where I make the list.
Rather I made a separate class for generating a sequence of random shipDetails. This runs a for loop and calls the randomGenerator class a to make a shipDetails object. The shipDetails is then stored to an Array list. This is repeated a random number of times.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class listOfShips {

    public ArrayList<shipDetails> list(){

        int requestedNumber = (int)(Math.random() *(30 - 10 + 1) + 10);;


        ArrayList<shipDetails> listo = new ArrayList<shipDetails>();

        for(int i = 0; i <= requestedNumber; i++){
            randomShipMaker random = new randomShipMaker();
            shipDetails randomy = random.randomShip();

            listo.add(randomy);

        }

        return listo;
    }

}
```

Then I can access the list class to get the ArrayList of random shipDetails which I can search, add to and delete from using my project.

-Andrew